# Electric field inside a conductive spherical shell

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

We have a conductive spherical shell and a point charge $q$ near it.

And Is the field inside the spherical shell (where is in fact not inside of the conductor) zero?

Answer (score 2):

The free charges of the conductive shell will find their place on the outer surface of the shell in such a way that the electric field will be zero inside the volume enclosed by the shell, as well as in the shell itself (assuming that the charge $q$ is outside the shell). Note that it does not need to be spherical, but only to enclose completely some given volume.

Comment: Inside I mean in the shell where is in fact not in the conductive

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood. I will edit my answer. You may want to do the same with your question.

Comment: sorry sir, but you haven't edited it. your editing will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Mohi Well, I did edit my answer, you can see the edits by clicking on the "edited x hours ago" button.

Comment: so, when free charges go to the outer surface of the shell, we have some free charges ( from the opposite sign ) on the inner surface of the shell. what about the field they make?

Comment: @Mohi  At equilibrium, all charges (positive and negative) find their place on the outer surface of the spherical shell. Inside the conductive shell, positive and negative charges cancel each other, and the electric field is zero. Same for the inner surface.

Comment: sorry but can draw that if it's possible for you and show the exact place of the charges

Comment: The exact place and density depends of the geometry and the location of the exterior charge $q$. I won't be able to draw it for you, sorry.

Comment: sir, is the pic I added the true general place of the charge?

Comment: No, the positive charges should be outside too. If for example $q$ is positive, then the negative charges would be outside of the shell and close to $q$, whereas the positive will be more on the opposite side (but still outside the shell).

Comment: BTW, you have modified your question and now my answer looks a bit strange. I would not recommend changing too much a question.